# Singular Homology - Why is $B_p(M)$ a normal subgroup of $Z_p(M)$?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a topological space, $Z_p(M)$ the set of singular $p$-cycles in $M$, and $B_p(M)$ the set of singular $p$-boundaries. In order to take the quotient $\dfrac{Z_p(M)}{B_p(M)}$, we need $B_p(M)\lhd Z_p(M)$. I am trying to prove this.

In order to prove this, it suffices to show that for any $c\in Z_p(M)$ and any $b\in B_p(M)$, $cbc^{-1}\in B_p(M)$. So I need to find a $(p+1)$-chain $b'$ such that $\partial b'=cbc^{-1}$. How can I find $b'$?

I wonder if it involves using the definition of $\partial$, that is,
$$\partial b'=\sum_{i=1}^p (-1)^i b'\circ F_{i,p},$$
where $F_{i,p}$ are the face maps, but I can't see how it would help to set this equal to $cbc^{-1}$.

**Edit:** By definition, $Z_p(M)=\ker\partial_n$ and $B_p(M)=\text{im}\partial_{n+1}$. And since $\partial^2=0$, $\text{im}\partial_{n+1}\leq\ker\partial_n$. But I still cannot see why $B_p(M)$ is normal in $Z_p(M)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, recall that $Z_p(M)$ is a subgroup of $C_p(M)$, the group of $p$-chains group, that is to say the free abelian group generated on the set of all singular $p$-simplices on $M$. Hence every subgroup of $C_p(M)$ is abelian as well.

Since $Z_p(M)$ is an abelian group, it is sufficient to check that $B_p(M)$ is just a subgroup.

But this is obvious since, as you say $B_p(M)=\mathrm{im}(\partial)$.